# C++ map with constructor and parameter

Tags: c++, parameters, constructor, stdmap, derived-class

I want to have an unordered map with a string and a std::function that call a constructor a class to make a shared_ptr. But I'm stuck, I don't know what I should add as a second member of my map I've tried several things and I don't know what to do finally ...

```
#include <functional>
#include <iostream>
#include <memory>
#include <string>
#include <unordered_map>
 
class A
{
public:
    A(const std::string &name){_name = name;}
    using Ptr = std::shared_ptr<A>;
private:
    std::string _name;
};

class BA : public A 
{
public:
    BA(const std::string &name) : A(name) {}
    using Ptr = std::shared_ptr<BA>;
};

class BB : public A 
{
public:
    BB(const std::string &name) : A(name) {}
    using Ptr = std::shared_ptr<BB>;
};

int main()
{
    static const std::unordered_map<std::string, std::function<A::Ptr(const std::string &)>> mapStringConstructor
    {
        {"A", A::A(const std::string &)},
        {"BA", BA::BA(const std::string &)},
        {"BB", BB::BB(const std::string &)}
    };
    return 0;
}
```

Thank in advance,

Comment: Constructors are a special type of functions. You can't call them, you can't get address of them, you can't store them. If you show us how do you want to use that map, we may be able to suggest alternatives (probably a factory pattern or something alike).

Comment: Well the constructors don't return shared_ptrs, so the constructors certainly won't work.

Answer (score 1):

You may just want to pass a lambda instead:

```
static const std::unordered_map<std::string, std::function<A::Ptr(const std::string&)>> mapStringConstructor{
    {"A",  [](const std::string& str) { return std::make_shared<A>(str); }},
    {"BA", [](const std::string& str) { return std::make_shared<BA>(str); }},
    {"BB", [](const std::string& str) { return std::make_shared<BB>(str); }}};
```

To use a function template, do this:

```
template<class T>
std::shared_ptr<T> make_class(const std::string& str) {
  return std::make_shared<T>(str);
}

static const std::unordered_map<std::string, std::function<A::Ptr(const std::string&)>> mapStringConstructor{
        {"A",  make_class<A>},
        {"BA", make_class<BA>},
        {"BB", make_class<BB>}};
```

Comment: And if the repeated typing bothers you, you could make it a template function

Comment: Thanks David G ! 
How I can use a template function for that ?

Comment: @Castling See update